# SQL - How to call a part of query conditionally

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to write a SQL query like this:

do step1

do step2

do step3
- this step does a lot of stuffs: define variables, use some variables defined in step 1, query a lot of data into temporary table...

```
if(cond1)

   if(cond2)        
 
       Begin            
          do step 4             
          call step 3 here      
       End  
    else
    
      Begin             
           do step 5        
      End  
  else  
 
  Begin         
     call step 3 here   
  End
```

How to make step 3 a reusable query to avoid calling step 3 unnecessarily? notice that step 3 should be a part of the whole query

When I try to create a @step3Query NVARCHAR(MAX), SET @step3Query = '...'
Then call this query in appropriated places by call "EXEC sp_executesql @step3Query". But I got a lot of errors, and I am not sure that is a correct way to do task like that.
Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one method that could work (depending on your exact circumstance). The main thing for this is that it's easy, as well as easy to read.

You could have 3 variables to use as flags e.g., @Query3_Flag, @Query4_flag, @Query5_flag.

Your conditional checks just set these flags e.g.,

```
IF (condition1)
    BEGIN
    SET @Query4_Flag = 1;
    SET @Query3_flag = 1;
    SET @Query5_flag = 0;
    END
```

Before each of queries 3, 4 and 5, have the IF statement check the flag and only run the query if the flag is set to 1 e.g.,

```
IF @Query3_Flag = 1 
    BEGIN
    (run Query 3)
    END
```

Note that the queries will need to be in the correct order.

Comment: Thanks Seanb for your answer but the point is that the subquery(step3) use some variables defined in step1 and step2. Its also define some other variables which will be used later in step4 and so on.. When I define @step3Query NVARCHAR(MAX) like that, I got errors like "Must declare the scalar variable..."

Comment: Sorry, I was suggesting putting all the SQL into one big script rather than being called elsewhere (rather than being called externally). Note that if you're using Dynamic SQL, you need to be very careful how you refer to variables - your issue won't be sequencing, but will be how to do the code properly - search here in SO for answers relating to variables and dynamic SQL.

Comment: After few hour struggling with it, I found that your answer is correct. We also have a alternative way to do it by using GOTO keyword. Thank you very much for your help.

I mark you answer and also make it clearer how to use GOTO keyword as I have just mentioned in a updated session as I cannot format code here in this comment